# Why matplotlib doesn't update in Anaconda to the 2.0 version

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, libraries, conda

I was lately trying to update all my Anaconda packages:

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda
```

Some of them still were not updated, so I also did `conda update --all`.
Right now my `conda version : 4.3.16`, which seems to be the latest release. However, for some reason, matplotlib still has old version:

```
conda list
matplotlib                1.5.1               np111py35_0
```

According to the [Anaconda changelog](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/changelog), it should be updated to 2.0 version: `matplotlib from 1.5.3 to 2.0.0`. 
My installed python version is `3.5.2`, if this matters.

**UPD**: Seems that spyder-app is blocking update because of problem with dependencies:

```
 conda install anaconda=4.3.1
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - anaconda 4.3.1* -> spyder 3.1.2 py34_0
  - spyder-app -> spyder 2.3.3
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.

conda install matplotlib=2
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
 - matplotlib 2.0*
 - spyder-app -> spyder 2.3.0 -> pyqt 4.* -> qt >=4.8.6,<5.0
 - spyder-app -> spyder 2.3.0 -> pyqt 4.* -> sip >=4.16.4,<4.18
 Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

**UPD2**: Problem was solved by removing spyder-app:

```
conda remove spyder-app
conda update anaconda
```

Matlotlib was updated to the 2.0 version, among other updated packages. I also checked if Spyder IDE still works, and it still is able to run.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It probably is a dependency conflict. The `anaconda` package is just a meta-package that bundles packages, if some package can't be updated because of a package you installed (maybe requiring `matplotlib < 2`, or even indirectly by requiring a package and version that matplotlib depends on) then you probably can't install the newest version of the `anaconda` package. You could try to install the newest `anaconda` package (currently 4.3.1) yourself:

```
conda install anaconda=4.3.1
```

But you can also try to install a specific version of `matplotlib` manually and see what happens (there should be an instructive message if it can't install it because of dependencies):

```
conda install matplotlib=2
```

---

In your case it's `spyder-app` that is responsible. It's a deprecated package and not included in newer versions of anaconda so one possibility is to remove it:

```
conda remove spyder-app
```

and then try the update of `anaconda` or `matplotlib`.

Another way would be to create a new environment and then you can choose which environment to use when:

```
conda install -n mynewenvironment python=3.5 anaconda
```

and then use the new environment when you need `matplotlib` 2 and the old environment if you need `spyder-app` (and don't care about the matplotlib version).

Comment: @Antonio Could you edit that into your question (including the command you used?) However oz see, that `spyder-app` is blocking the update (and you probably installed that manually, right?) so you could try to remove it (`conda remove spyder-app`, it's deprecated anyway) and then update `matplotlib` and/or `anaconda`.

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem (although I do not remember installing that manually, and never used it, I think it was included in previous version of anaconda). After removing spyder-app, new version of anaconda with matplotlib 2.0 was successfully installed with `conda update anaconda`.
Also seems that spyder-app is not needed: I just checked if `Spyder` can run without it, and it starts fine.